# How can I reopen STDIN <> in perl?

Tags: perl, stdin, loops

How can I open STDIN for the second time?

Let say I have this data

```
John Smith  25  O   ATG 180
Peter Jackson   40  AB  GGTA    173
Carl Anderson   32  A   GGT 172
```

And I have this code

```
while( my $line = <>)  {
    print $line;
}
while( my $line = <>)  {
    print $line;
}
```

I want it to print

```
John Smith  25  O   ATG 180
Peter Jackson   40  AB  GGTA    173
Carl Anderson   32  A   GGT 172
John Smith  25  O   ATG 180
Peter Jackson   40  AB  GGTA    173
Carl Anderson   32  A   GGT 172
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't, you have emptied the stream. If you want to use it again, put the lines in an array.

```
my @lines;
while( my $line = <>)  {
    print $line;
    push @lines, line;
}

foreach my $line (@lines)  {
    print $line;
}
```

Or, write to a file and get a filehandle on the file.

Comment: More succinctly: `my @lines = <>; print( (@lines) x 2 )`

Answer (score 5):

If STDIN is attached to a file, then you can `seek(STDIN, 0, 0)`, but in general, you can't do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could always grab the filename instead of using STDIN.

```
$fn = shift;
open(MyFile,"< $fn") || die "cant open $fn $!";
while(MyFile) { } # first time thru
seek MyFile,0,0
while(MyFile) { } # second time thru
```

If it's a list of files you can loop through them.